# Adding keywords programmatically using the display property

Tags: font-lock, backquote

I've added some keywords using the following construct (where `tag-todo` and `tag-note` are variable holding a SVG image and `tag-key ()` is a function returning a SVG image):

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
        '(("\\(\:TODO\:\\)" 1 `(face nil display ,tag-todo))
          ("\\(\:NOTE\:\\)" 1 `(face nil display ,tag-note))
          ("\\(=[0-9a-zA-Z- ]+?=\\)" 1
                              `(face nil display ,(tag-key (match-string 0))))))
```

This works great (see [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/jc4uou/tags_everywhere/)) but I would like now to do the same using a list of regexp / tag (or function):

```
(setq tags '((":TODO:"            . tag-todo)
             (":NOTE:"            . tag-note)
             ("=[0-9a-zA-Z- ]+?=" . tag-key)))
```

I can iterate over the list using `dolist` but then I'not sure how to write the actual call to `font-lock-add-keywords` (building the regexp and make sure the tag variable (or function) is called):

```
(dolist (item tags)
  (let ((regexp (car item))
        (tag    (cdr item)))
    (message (format "%s : %s" regexp tag))
    ;; HOW TO CALL font-lock-add-keywords with regexp and tag ?
))
```

**Update**

I've tried using mapcar, but the `(cdr item)` does not evaluate to the actual tag content.

```
(defun f (item)
  `( ,(concat "\\(" (car item) "\\)") 1
     `(face nil display (cdr item))))
(mapcar 'f tags)
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may get you there.  (Do you really want/need a `\` before each colon (`:`)?)

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  "..."
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil (mapcar 'bar tags)))

(defun bar (pat.fac)
  "..."
  (let ((pat  (format "\\(%s\\)" (car pat.fac)))
        (fac  (cdr pat.fac)))
    (when (eq fac 'tag-key) (setq fac  '(tag-key (match-string 0))))
    (setq fac  ``(face nil display ,,fac))
    `(,pat 1 ,fac)))
```

`(mapcar 'bar tags)` returns this:

```lisp
(("\\(:TODO:\\)" 1
  `(face nil display ,tag-todo))
 ("\\(:NOTE:\\)" 1
  `(face nil display ,tag-note))
 ("\\(=[0-9a-zA-Z- ]+?=\\)" 1
  `(face nil display ,(tag-key (match-string 0)))))
```

The key to the trouble you were having, I think, is to use two levels of backquoting.

Comment: Thanks and you're right with the two levels backquoting. I suspected I may need it but had no clue how to do it.

Comment: Just realized I'll need a small modification to test if the second item is a variable or a function (instead of testing for the name).